# Initialize JSON object with undefined length arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to figure out how to define arrays in JSON Objects.
For example,

```
//Lets create a JSON Object
var foo = {
    "id" : "",
    "data" : [
        {"data_id" : "", "data_status" : "", "dataweight" : ""}
    ]
};
```

Seems to be correct if I want to access to the first row of data.

Now how can I push data in over rows of the array? For example :

```
foo.data[4].data_id = something;
```

I think I misunderstood how to define JSON objects. Or maybe there are tricks to access to undefined length arrays in JSON objects, but I don't know them.

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined length arrays"? The length of an array is always the value of the largest item index plus one.

Comment: What's `foo.data[4]` ?there is no `data[4]` there is only `data[0]`. You only have one item in the array.

Comment: Please may you clear up what the actual question is?

Comment: I cannot know in advance the number of items in the data array,
that is why I called it "undefined lenght".

Comment: @Royi Namir I saw that, II want to create an array and then resize it later when i have the information about his lenght.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, as soon as you know the array size

```js
var foo = {
    "id" : "",
    "data" : [
        {"data_id" : "", "data_status" : "", "dataweight" : ""}
    ]
};

var arraySize = 4;

for(var i = 1 ; i < arraySize ; i++){
 var el = {"data_id" : i,"data_status" : "", "dataweight" : ""} ;
 foo.data.push(el);
}
console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the json is undefined by `typeof obj === "undefined"`

example, checking if `foo.data[4]` is undefined and init it if undefined.

```
if ( typeof foo.data[4] === "undefined" ) foo.data[4] = {};
```

You can now assign `foo.data[4].data_id = something;`

**Note:** This is assuming that `foo` and `foo.data` are defined

Answer (score 0):

Array element `foo.data[4]` doesn't exist yet. Try creating it first before changeing one of its attributes.

```
foo.data[4] = {};
foo.data[4].data_id = "Something";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to push then try

```
foo.data.push(something);
```

It is not a right method to assign to an array index for a push operation, because the index may not be existing so go for `push` operation. 
Hope this will help you,